# Paste Chart and Table from excel to existing word document into a specific part of the document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, copy, paste

I am using the below VBA code to copy and paste a table and a chart from an excel spreadsheet to a template word document.

When I run the below macro the chart and table are pasted at the top of the document. Does anyone know of a way to select where the chart and table will be pasted?

Also if there is a way to format the table so it auto fits into the doc that would be great.

```
Sub ExportChartandTableToExistingTemplatePara()

'Declare Word Object Variables
Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim WrdTbl As Word.Table
Dim wordTable As Object

'Declare Excel Object Variables
Dim Chrt As ChartObject
Dim ExcListObj As ListObject


'Open Template

Dim oAPP As Object

Set oAPP = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")

oAPP.Visible = True

oAPP.Documents.Open Filename:="C:\Users\michael.okeefe\Documents\PurchaseUpdateReportExampleTest.docx"


'Create a Reference to the chart I want to Export
Set Chrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
Chrt.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

'Paste into Word Document
With oAPP.Selection

.PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject
End With

'Create a Reference to List Object to Copy
Set ExcListObj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
ExcListObj.Range.Copy


'Paste into Word Document
With oAPP.Selection
    .PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False



End With


End Sub
```

I was wanting the table to show after the first paragraph and the chart to show on a later page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a confused mess. You declare the required objects at the top of the routine, don't use any of them, then declare `oAPP As Object`.

I have made your code consistent and shown you how to paste the table into a known location. You'll need to identify where the chart needs to go and use similar code for that.

```
Sub ExportChartandTableToExistingTemplatePara()

    'Declare Word Object Variables
    Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim WrdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WrdTbl As Word.Table

    'Declare Excel Object Variables
    Dim Chrt As ChartObject
    Dim ExcListObj As ListObject

    'Open Template

    Set WrdApp = New Word.Application

    WrdApp.Visible = True

    
    Set WrdDoc = WrdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\michael.okeefe\Documents\PurchaseUpdateReportExampleTest.docx")

    'Create a Reference to the chart I want to Export
    Set Chrt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    Chrt.Chart.ChartArea.Copy

    'Paste into Word Document
    'you need to identify exactly where this needs to be pasted

    'Create a Reference to List Object to Copy
    Set ExcListObj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    ExcListObj.Range.Copy

    'Paste into Word Document
    WrdDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Timothy, thank you very much for your help with this. I agree my code was a mess, bodged together from multiple sources. If I was to have the Chart pasted into paragraph 5 what would I add to the code?

Comment: @Michael - Either `WrdDoc.Paragraphs(5).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartLinked` or `WrdDoc.Paragraphs(2).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=True, DataType:=wdPasteOLEObject`